# (MySQL) Getting error while changing root password

Tags: mysql, root, rdbms

I followed an official [reset root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) tutorial, but powershell(or cmd) keeps throwing errors for unknown reason.

When I type `mysqld --init-file=C:\\reset.txt` I get this error: (I checked my `reset.txt`'s path. It is in the `C:\`.)

> mysqld : The term 'mysqld' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + mysqld --init-file=C:\reset.txt
>   + ~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysqld:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Next, when I type just `mysqld` only for testing, the terminal throws this error:

> [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
>
> [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

At first I thought there was a path problem. So I added `mysqld` path into `Environment Variable` and typed `mysqld` again. But still the terminal throws the second error.

[image]

I'm using Windows and even I formatted my PC to test this yet still it gives me those errors.

Can somebody give me any solutions to resolve this?

Comment: Does the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` directory exist and contain a file called `mysqld.exe`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, the folder contains `mysql.exe`.

Comment: Then, it is just an issue with PATH variable within PowerShell window? Does everything work if you switch working directory to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` and launch the program from there?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Seems like `mysql` and `mysqld` won't work. but I figured out. Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. Unlikely the instruction manual, you don't have to stop MySQL service in the `Services` window.

All you have to do is:

### 1. Open `CMD` & Use `use mysql;`

In normal `CMD`

- Type `mysql -u root -p` for logging in MySQL.
- Type your current password
- Type `use mysql;`

In `MySQL CLT`

- Type your current password
- Type `use mysql;`

---

### 2. Change the password

- Type `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '[desired_password]';`
- Type `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- Type quit; for logging out.

You can check more information from here: [Resetting MySQL Password (Stack Exchange)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: If you know current password, why do you need a reset in the first place? I suspect you actually meant a regular password change, but looked up for instructions to recover a lost password instead.